# program executing for 2 days

Tags: memory, java, top, virtual-memory, profiling

I have a java program which implements the Hungarian algorithm. I made changes to the existing code in such a way that the input is read from file. I have a pretty huge input around 32,000 rows for which I am calculating the maximum edge weight.

The problem is, when I run the program using the command,

```
java Hungarian_algorithm.java
```

for which, I got an error, `java.lang.outofMemoryError:java Heap space error`. So, after researching a bit on the error, I ran the program using the below command.

```
java -d64 -Xms6g -Xmx8g Hungarian_algorithm
```

I started the execution 2 days back and the program has still not produced any output. So, I decided to check the memory consumption in the server.

**Output of top command**

```
PID    USER     PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
20760 ramesh    20   0 8482m 5.9g 3484 S  101 75.9   3099:13 java
```

**output of free -m command**

```
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7991       7937         54          0         37       1432
-/+ buffers/cache:       6467       1524
Swap:        30514       4626      25888
```

Should I wait for the program to produce some output or some error atleast or kill the execution of the program?

Comment: I think you will get better response at Stackoverflow for this question.

Comment: oh ok. I thought, since the program is getting executed in a linux box, may be from memory consumption, we will be able to figure out something.

Comment: To get some clues you can check the process id and use `jstack` to see what is currently going on.

Comment: If I check the `jstack` output, I see the threads are waiting (on object Monitor). Although, I am not sure on what that means.

Comment: That might be a deadlock there. Look up on web for "java deadlock"  should pull up something useful.

Comment: For the next version, maybe adding a little bit more logging would be a good idea...

Comment: If this is a network file with 32000 edges, you should expect it to take a while.

Comment: So, do you think waiting for 3 to 4 days might be a good idea? I am getting the output for 2000 edges in 196 seconds. So, I am pretty sure there is no memory leak in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the question and comments, you could look up the java running call stack via the `jstack` command:

```
jstack processid
```

If there are some threads waiting for a long time on some condition then it is most likely a deadlock. A deadlock might be rare on production grade code but common on experimental multithreaded code. In the former case, a rerun might fix the issue but in the later case a detailed debugging might be required.

Comment: +1 Worth noting that a if it was just a deadlock the process would appear idle, so there's something more to this that's causing one or more threads to spin wheels and tie up a lot of processing time -- e.g., somebody is busy-wait polling.